# Is a locally constant function on the complement of a null-set measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

If I have a surface $M$ and a function $\ f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is 
locally constant on the complement of a measure-zero set, i.e., there is a measure-zero set $V \subset M$, such that for every $x \in M \smallsetminus V$, there exists a neighbourhood $U \subset M \smallsetminus V$ of $x$ with $\ f(x) = f(y)$ for all $y \in U$.

Is this function measurable on $M$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I am assuming by "surface" you mean a 2-manifold, i.e., in particular it is countably based.

Because $M$ is countably based, we may find a countable open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $M \setminus V$ such that $f$ is locally constant on each $U_i$.  Since $V$ is measurable, so is $M \setminus V$ and also each $U_i$. Now it is easy to see that $f$ is measurable: if $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(S)$ is measurable because it is a countable union of measurable sets:
$$f^{-1}(S) = \bigcup \{ U_i \mid f(U_i) \cap S \neq \emptyset \}.$$